# Javascript Object.assign not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript

In the following Javascript, the result is that it displays 1, 2, 3.  I would expect it to display: 1, 2, 2.  My understanding was that `Object.assign` would copy the values in an object.

```js
var myobj = {
  mynum: 1,
  mystr: "test",
  mydata: 6
}
alert(myobj.mynum);

let secondobj = myobj;
secondobj.mynum = 2;
alert(myobj.mynum);

let thirdobj = Object.assign(myobj);
thirdobj.mynum = 3;
alert(myobj.mynum);
```

Comment: It doesn't [just clone an object given a single parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and I'm not sure why you expect it to.

Comment: 1, 2, 2, is what it will produce.  #3 is assigned to thirdobj, which is not same as myobj, so myobj will still be 2.

Comment: @Aragorn that is wrong. It produces 1, 2, 3 and `thirdobj` is definitely the *exact same* object as the rest: `thirdobh === myobj //true`

Comment: @VLAZ - duh!, I missed that error on obj.assign, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition is Object.assign(target, source)

So, this would work:

```
var myobj = {mynum: 1, mystr: "test", mydata: 6}
alert(myobj.mynum);

let secondobj = myobj;
secondobj.mynum = 2;
alert(myobj.mynum);

let thirdobj = {};
Object.assign(thirdobj, myobj);
thirdobj.mynum = 3;
alert(myobj.mynum);
```

You could also use:

```
let thirdobj = { ... myobj};
thirdobj.mynum = 3;
alert(myobj.mynum);
```

for brevity

Answer (score 2):

It is the same object

```
var foo = {}
var bar = Object.assign(foo)
console.log(foo === bar) // true
```

To copy object values use

```
var bar = Object.assign({}, foo)
```

or spread operator (new in ECMAScript 2018)

```
var bar = { ...foo };
```

For your case

```
let thirdobj = Object.assign({}, myobj);
```